# Select value from stored procedure which outputs a table

Tags: select, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

I have a procedure which returns a select statement output after a set of calculation. The output on executing the procedure will be as below:

`exec proc1 empID`

Output is as below

`col1    col2    col3   col4    col5`
`2014      2      33     330     29`
`2014      3      10     34      12`
`2015      1      25     60      55`

Now I have a main select statement which gets many columns by joining different tables.

I need to retrieve the above columns (output of stored procedure `proc1`) to the main select statement, for the `empID` which is available.

Something like below:

`select empID, empName, empSal, 
(select col3 from [exec proc1 empID] where col2=1),
empDept
from tblemployee`

Is it possible to do? I am expecting 25 in the 4th column of the above query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either `User-defined function` or a `view` instead of a stored procedure.

sp doesn't allow `select` to use in it.

or you can

- create a table variable to store the result returned from the stored procedure

`Declare @TempTable  Table (...)--declare all columns`

- insert the output of the stored proc into the table variable and then

`Insert @TempTable   Exec storedProcname params`

- Join the Temp table variable exactly as per your need

**Note**

But the above method has a limitation
The problem with  INSERT @Temptable  is that an

> INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested

. it will break,if your stored procedure already has an INSERT EXEC in it.